# Web Api not converting json empty strings values to null

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

Example Json:
{"Field1":"","Field2":null}.

In MVC, Field1 would be converted to null by default.
I tried the [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true)] attribute, (which should be the default anyway) and it did not make a difference.

I'm using Web Api 2.1

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that the MVC DisplayFormat have no effect on WebAPI, these are two independent frameworks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in C# an empty string is not the same as a null reference, and json.NET which is the underlying json implementation decided to avoid automatic conversions.

You can add the following custom converter to deal with that

```
public class EmptyToNullConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private JsonSerializer _stringSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string value = _stringSerializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            value = null;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        _stringSerializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    }
}
```

and to use it in your class decorate the properties you want to convert with

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(EmptyToNullConverter))]
public string FamilyName { get; set; }
```

You can add this converter to the `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters` and it will apply to all strings instead. Note that it required the private member _stringSerializer otherwise it will stackoverflow. The member is not required if you just decorate the string property directly.

in WebApiConfig.cs add the following line:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new EmptyToNullConverter());
```

Comment: Can you explain why it stack overflows?

Comment: Great question, I do not recall, you can just try it without the extra field and capture the callstack